# Creating a button to launch a jQuery function rather than instantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that creates an image:

```
<script>
domtoimage.toJpeg(document.getElementById('print_screen'), { quality: 0.70 })

              .then(function (dataUrl) {
                  var link = document.createElement('a');
                  link.download = 'invoice.jpeg';
                  link.href = dataUrl;
                  link.click();
});
</script>
```

The problem is that it launches immediately when loading the page. I want to do a button like:

```
<a class="btn" href="" onclick="printFunction()">Click here to print</a>
```

I tried wrapping the `domtoimage` inside `function printFunction` but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: make 'link' as global variable and remove link.click() in promise callback

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, then you can wrap your function in the document.ready function, like this, if not your `domtoimage.toJpeg` function will be executed when browser parse that tag.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var btnHandler = function(){
              domtoimage.toJpeg(document.getElementById('print_screen'), { quality: 0.70 })

              .then(function (dataUrl) {
                  var link = document.createElement('a');
                  link.download = 'invoice.jpeg';
                  link.href = dataUrl;
                  link.click();
    };
    var $btn = $("a.btn").click(btnHandler);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

$('#buttonid').click (function (){
Your code here
});

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering click event in promise callback.
A work around is to comment `link.click()` in promise callback and trigger the `click event` inside another `function`

To do so 
comment `link.click()`

```
<script>
    var link=null;
    domtoimage.toJpeg(document.getElementById('print_screen'), { quality: 0.70 })

                  .then(function (dataUrl) {
                      link = document.createElement('a');
                      link.download = 'invoice.jpeg';
                      link.href = dataUrl;
                      // Comment the below line
                      // link.click();
    });   
</script>
```

Trigger the click event in custom function like below:

```
<a class="btn" href="" onclick="printFunction()">Click here to print</a>

<script>
    function printFunction(){
        // trigger the click event in printFunction
        link.click();
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

in the function write this:

```
var srciptElement = document.createElement('script');

scriptElement.attr("src",the url of the jquery");

document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
```